# Using Identity Server 3, ClaimsPrinciple null even after successful bearer token authentication

Tags: asp.net, ssl, asp.net-web-api, owin, identityserver3

I have a test console app which I'm pointing at a local instance of Identity Server 3 to request an access token. The following code does this and returns my token fine (passing a single scope `"scope.test.client"`).

```
    static TokenResponse GetClientToken(string clientId, string clientSecret, string[] scopes)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(string.Concat(ID_BASE_URI, ID_URL_TOKEN));

        var client = new TokenClient(
            uri.AbsoluteUri,
            clientId,
            clientSecret);

        return client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync(string.Join(" ", scopes)).Result;
```

I then use this token to call an API also running locally. This takes the `TokenResponse` obtained above and passed it to this method:

```
    static void CallApi(string url, TokenResponse response)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.SetBearerToken(response.AccessToken);
                Console.WriteLine(client.GetStringAsync(url).Result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception: {0}", x.Message));
        }
    }
```

The API (an ASP.NET WebApi project) uses an Owin Startup class to enforce bearer token authentication for all requests:

```
        appBuilder.Map(baseApiUrl, inner =>
        {
            inner.UseWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

            // Enforce bearer token authentication for all API requests
            inner.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://identityserver/core",
                ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,

                RequiredScopes = new[] { "scope.test.client" }
            });
        });
```

It also ensures all API requests are handled by a custom authorize attribute:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new DefaultApiAuthorizeAttribute());
```

Debugging this API, the first line in my overridden `OnAuthorize` method (in `DefaultApiAuthorizeAttribute`) is this:

```
var caller = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
```

If I break on this line I can see that `actionContext.RequestContext.Principal` is always null. However, I can see that `((System.Web.Http.Owin.OwinHttpRequestContext)actionContext.RequestContext).Request.Headers` contains an Authorization header with the bearer token passed from my console app.

So it would seem that the API project is not authenticating the bearer token. Certainly the Identity Server logs suggest it isn't being hit at all after issuing the initial access token. So I'd appreciate your expert advice about why this might not be happening, or at least some pointers about where to look.

I suspect it might have something to do with SSL. Both sites are hosted locally under self-signed SSL certs, although Identity Server is configured to not require SSL and uses the idsrv3test.pfx development certificate for signing. I do have another test MVC web app which delegates authentication to the same IS3 instance which works fine locally, so I believe my IS3 instance is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine a range of possible issues could have the impact I described, but in my case I was able to find the cause by adding a diagnostics log to my consuming API. This led me to discover that the problem was an assembly conflict. The Owin middleware was looking for a Newtonsoft.JSON assembly with version 8.0.0.0 but my consuming API (actually running on top of a CMS intance) was using 7.0.0.0.

For anyone else who wants to find the answer fast, rather than spend hours tweaking configurations, here's the documentation that describes how to add this logging: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/consuming/diagnostics.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication` **before** you call `UseWebApi`. When you set up an OWIN Middleware Pipeline, the order is important.

In your case, Web API will be handling your requests before they get sent onto Identity Server (if they get sent on at all).

Comment: Thank you. However in trying to resolve this I'd already read that the order was important so had experimented with switching this order. Before that they were in the order you suggest but behaviour was the same.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use local validation on your tokens?

Comment: Not sure what that means, sorry. The token was issued by IS3 so must validated by IS3 right?

Comment: No, not necessarily. It's much cleverer than that. Anyway, try removing the validation mode from your config and see if that makes a difference. If it does, I can point you in the direction of an explanation of the validation process.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me Kirk. I've made the two changes you suggest, calling `UseWebApi` after `UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication` and removing the ValidationMode set, but not observing any difference. My `actionContext.RequestContext.Principal` is still null.

Comment: No joy. I've set up a basic version of what you've described and it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. It's good to know my core configuration is OK. I guess there must be something going on in the wider application. I will step back and start on a new tack, maybe set up from scratch again. Will report back if I find the issue.

Comment: For what it's worth I did find that when authenticating JWT Bearer tokens with `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` the order was important!  That call had to preceed `UseWebApi` otherwise the principal on the request context would be null.